# analyze a query postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query below, may i please know what needs to be done to reduce execution time from 18sec

the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (player_name) server_name, player_anme, logged_at, joined_at 
FROM player_cache 
WHERE server_name ILIKE '{query[0]}' 
AND logged_at > (now() - interval '{history} hour') 
ORDER BY player_name,logged_at desc;
```

The execution plan

```
Unique (cost=14326.21..14326.25 rows=7 width=82) (actual time=18907.017..18907.049 rows=32 loops=1)
  -> Sort (cost=14326.21..14326.23 rows=7 width=82) (actual time=18907.015..18907.023 rows=81 loops=1)
    Sort Key: player_name, logged_at DESC
    Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 36kB
  -> Index Scan using idx_logged_at on player_cache (cost=0.56..14326.11 rows=7 width=82) (actual time=5.605..18906.463 rows=81 loops=1)
    Index Cond: (logged_at > (now() - '30:00:00'::interval))
    Filter: ((server_name)::text ~~* 'Server-1'::text)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 79825
Planning Time: 0.665 ms
Execution Time: 18907.108 ms
```

Comment: [Edit] the question, if you got something to add. Don't use comments for that. Especially, if it's code you want to add, that's totally unreadable in comments.

Comment: An index on your `server_name` column could help. Also it seems that you don't have any pattern matching in your expression for ILIKE. In [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/237394) you'll find some possibilities, if you really need ILIKE.

Comment: What is `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query?  Turn track_io_timing on before running that if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) to speed up the `ILIKE` condition:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON player_cache USING gin (server_name gin_trgm_ops);
```